# Why I have space between anchor tag and span inside

Tags: html, css, cross-browser, stylesheet

I have a problem.
I have a list with link in all item of the list.
And when I want to add a span inside anchor tag, i have a space and can't remove it..

```
 <li class="elementMyAccount spaceTopBetweenElementMyAccount">

     <a href=""
         class="elementMyAccountText">
         Text4
         <div class="adressDescription" >(text4)</div>
     </a>
</li>
```

I send you jsFiddle to show you css and html:

https://jsfiddle.net/5fwvsqnb/10

I had remove this space line with change on my css, but it worked only on google chrome ... but not Safari and IE ( don't try others )

I changed css by :

```
#my-account .elementMyAccountText{
font-size: 15px;
position: absolute;
margin-left : 5px;
line-height:60px;
width:240px;
display: flex;
align-items: center;
}

#my-account .adressDescription{
display:block;
position:absolute;
font-size: 11px;
text-decoration: none;
margin-left: 40px;
line-height:15px;
display: block;
}
```

But maybe it's not the solution because on IE I have a space between my span and my text above.

Thanks all if you will try to help me !

Comment: I am not getting the space. Can you share screenshot of safari or IE?

Comment: you are not getting this : https://zupimages.net/viewer.php?id=20/21/ogmv.png ? 
What I want it's the second text in the span, just below my anchor text...

Comment: Why elementMyAccountText class have position: absolute;?

Comment: I think this is your expected output. https://prnt.sc/smb4vf     right?

Comment: Ah yes, it can be a mistake... If I remove position: absolute, the solution is to have margin-top: - 20px on my element adressDescription ?
Edit : Yes it's that what I want!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is in your code, `elementMyAccountText` class have `position: absolute;`.

If you want to display `TEXT` in left align with the center of the box then You can use `display: flex` to the `ul` and `li` and `align-items: center;` to the `li`.

If you want full box clickable then

Remove `height` from `elementMyAccount` class and add below code

```
ul li a{
width: 100%;
display: block;
padding: 20px 0; 
}
```

```css
.listElementMyAccount {
  margin-top: 50px;
}

.listElementMyAccount ul {
  margin-left: -8px;
  display: flex;
}

.elementMyAccount {
  border-radius: 7px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 60px;
  width: 240px;
  margin-left: 8px;
  margin-top: 8px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}


/*.elementMyAccountText{
 font-size: 15px;
 position: absolute;
 margin-left : 5px;
 line-height:60px;
 width:240px;
 height:60px;

}*/

.elementMyAccountImg {
  margin-left: 5px;
  opacity: 0.75;
  margin-right: 10px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.adressDescription {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 11px;
  text-decoration: none;
  line-height: 15px;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="listElementMyAccount">
  <ul>

    <li class="elementMyAccount">
      <a href="" class="elementMyAccountText">
                                    TEXT1
                                </a>
    </li>
    <li class="elementMyAccount">
      <a href="" class="elementMyAccountText">
                                    TEXT2
                                </a>
    </li>
    <li class="elementMyAccount">
      <a href="" class="elementMyAccountText">
                                    TEXT3
                                </a>
    </li>
    <li class="elementMyAccount">
      <a href="" class="elementMyAccountText">
                                    TEXT4
                                                                                                      <span class="adressDescription" >(text4)</span>
                                </a>
    </li>

  </ul>



</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, but little problem with your solution..
When i have to reduce my screen, elements are reduced too, but I prefer the old behaviour.. when you reduce, element go on an other line (I don't know if you understand)

Comment: If you resize the window then you have to use media query and add .listElementMyAccount ul (display:block)

Comment: If you don't want to change the behavior then you can do one thing.  Add your full CSS and add this css .elementMyAccount{position: relative;} and update this css
.elementMyAccountText{
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
transform: translateY(-50%);
padding: 20px 0;
width: 100%;
}

Answer (score 0):

I'm not specialist, but I guess, this is because render engine (i don't know to name that) cannot recognize your style e.g. -webkit-column-count. IE is not supporter, if is it, it will no longer soon. Forget about IE.